# Ajax jsonp ошибка 404 при отправке данных на стороннй сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Пытаюсь отправить данные с приложения на локальном хостинге на php обработчик расположенный на стороннем сайте но скрипт возвращает error 404
скрипт такой:

```
 $.ajax({
    url : 'http://*****.com/hyst/acore.php',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(json){
        alert('s');
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status+' '+thrownError);
    }
});
```

но почему то как не пробовал возвращает ошибку, не пойму в чем проблема?

upd: ссылка на файл обработчик 100% рабочая не раз проерял - файл на хостинге лежит и доступен если открыть его в браузере по ссылке

[не думаю что это критично но это js приложение которое в дальнейшем через cordova монтирую в android apk]

Comment: Эээм. 404 значит, что на сайте нет такого адреса.

Comment: @Alexey Ten как один из вариантов да, но адрес 100% есть в том плане что если я копирую ссылку в браузер то страница открывается. Но я до этого гуглил там были похожие вопросы в плане по таким же запросам ajax и у них были другие причины, в плане не отстутсвие страницы а что то другое

Comment: @dantelol возможно когда к серверу обращаются через ajax, то php скрипт приводит к редиректу на 404

Comment: @Misha Saidov но скрипт я сам писал там пока для теста только приемник данных стоит, даже не знаю вот в настройках сервера и хитаксес ничего такого не было..

Comment: Попробуй в php файле в самом начале тупо `echo "ok"; exit;` написать, а в js в `dataType: "html"` и смотри, есть ли ответ.

Comment: @Misha Saidov да вот к сожалению и так не работает, мне кажется это связанно с какими то ограничениями по передаче данных между разными доменами